# How to count the days from current date to the start date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have two dates

```
StartDate : 2020-11-02
EndDate : 2020-11-28
```

How do i create a DAX function that would count my current date against my start date until it reaches the end date.

For example, today is the `14th`  so if i had to count the `2nd` to the 14th i should get a count of `13` days, so my output would be 13.and when I reach the current date of 28th then my day count will be 27 and it ends there.

How do i achieve this in a power bi measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this measure

```
mx = 
var start_date = date( 2020, 11, 2) 
var end_date = date(2020,11,28)
var current_date = TODAY()
var future_date = date(2020,12,3)
var end_date_mod = min( current_date, end_date)
return
DATEDIFF( start_date, end_date_mod, day) +1
```

the `future_date` variable is for testing purposes, just replace the `end_date` with `future_date` in `end_date_mod` variable